# No content using fputc

Tags: c

I am attempting to complete a lab.
When I run this code nothing is written to the text file that is created. According to the lab it should write A thru Z to the text file.

```
//Example program #1. Chapter 29
// File Chapter29exl.c

/* The program open a file named letters.txt and prints A through Z in the file.
It then loops backward through the file printing each of the letters from z to A. */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
FILE * fptr;

main()
{
char letter;
int i;

fptr = fopen("letters.txt", "w+");

if (fptr == 0)
{
    printf(" There was an error while opening the file.\n");
    exit(1);
}

for (letter = 'A'; letter <= 'Z'; letter++)
{
    fputc(letter, fptr);
}

puts("Just wrote the letters A through Z");

//Now read the file backwards

fseek(fptr, -1, SEEK_END);  // Minus 1 byte from the end
printf("Here is the file backwards:\n");
for (i = 26; i > 0; i--)
{
    letter = fgetc(fptr);
    //Reads a letter, then backs up 2
    fseek(fptr, -2, SEEK_CUR);
    printf("The next letter is %c/\n, leeter");
}

fclose(fptr);
return(0);
}
```

The code created the file but it is blank.
Thanks

Comment: Some C library implementations I know require an `fflush()` between writing to the file and an `fseek()` if an `fseek()` is done after writing to the file.

Comment: `printf("The next letter is %c/\n, leeter");` <<-- there is no argument for the `%c` format qualifier.

Comment: Refer to the comment above by @wildplasser and then turn on all warnings because your compiler should have informed you of this problem.

Comment: See paragraph 7 of section 7.21.5.3 of https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf "output shall not be directly followed by input without an intervening call to the fflush function"

Comment: Rather than the useless error message provided by `printf(" There was an error while opening the file.\n");`, try `perror("letters.txt");`.  Main advantages: it prints the error to the correct stream, it provides a reason for the failure, and the error message it produces is (fairly) standardized.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: The section you cite does not say “output shall not be directly followed by input without an intervening call to the fflush function”. It says “… output shall not be directly followed by input without an intervening call to the `fflush` function or to a file positioning function (`fseek`, `fsetpos`, or `rewind`),…” and OP’s code has an intervening call to `fseek`.

Answer (score 1):

In line, you're not passing the variable for `%c`, only a string

```
printf("The next letter is %c/\n, leeter");
```

It should be:

```
printf("The next letter is %c/\n", letter);
```

**You can detect this** easily if you look at the **compiler warnings**. By default, GCC produces the following warning for your code:

```
 warning: format '%c' expects a matching 'int' argument [-Wformat=]
       printf("The next letter is %c/\n, leeter");
```

Indicating the argument is missing.

Comment: This does not address why the file is empty, though, since the expectation is that data is written to the file via the previous `fputc`

Comment: @WilliamPursell: The file is not empty. OP incorrectly concluded the file was empty based on the output of the program, not examination of the file through other means.

Comment: Thanks. This did the trick.  printf("The next letter is %c/\n", letter); I'll have to look into why the compiler warnings didn't catch this.